# Cursor should appear from start in editText in android

Tags: android

I have a screen which have editText and a button, now when we click on the button it will fetch the Text from another screen and set to the editText.
The problem is when the text has been set to edittext cursor position is coming at last. I want that cursor position should appear from start.

Any Idea??
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MODIFIED**

```
editText.requestFocus();
editText.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: The shown code is f9 Are you using these methods after the text update  is done...i.e after setText(with new value)